# What efficient ways are there to earn coins?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

I just looked at the [Coin Dungeons](http://puzzledragonx.com/en/coin-dungeons.asp) and am a little shocked at how expensive the most expensive ones are. Secondly, I know that some players have [999,999,999+](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/198403/what-is-the-maximum-amount-of-coins) coins. I'm familiar with [Weekend Dungeon](http://puzzledragonx.com/en/dungeon.asp?d=21) (and I won't say more about it to be answered), but I feel like there is at least one comparable alternative. I recall mention of Gold Dragons.

How do I make bank?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is the weekend dungeon.

Find a friend who has Ganesha and bust out your best team to take on weekend dungeon master. You can easily squeeze 400K coins in a run.

I would not sell metal dragons for gold, even though they are good payout, as they are better EXP food.